# Attempting to add timestamps to a log with pings, but when I use a streamwriter to add timestamps it nullifies the console pings

Tags: vb.net, timestamp, ping

I'm attempting to make a program that will ping an IP x amount of times and then write the results to a log and email that log. It worked fine up until I decided to add timestamps to it as well. When I tried running it with the extra code in for timestamps it made it so that the console won't ping the IP but the writer will write the timestamps to the file and I'm not sure why. Here's the code for that sub.

```
Sub ping(ByVal interval As Integer, ByVal ip As String, ByVal desktop As String, ByRef counter As Integer, ByRef boolping As Boolean)
    Dim now As New DateTime
    Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(desktop & "\log.txt")
    While counter > 0 And boolping = True
        now = DateTime.Now
        writer.WriteLine(now)
        boolping = My.Computer.Network.Ping(ip)
        Process.Start("CMD", "/c ping " & ip & " >> " & desktop & "\log.txt")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval)
        counter = counter - 1
    End While
    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `Process.Start` ? you have all you need in the .NET framework for accomplishing this.

Here's how to do it:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim address As String = "www.yahoo.com"
    Dim log As String = "log.txt"
    Dim count As Integer = 5
    For i As Integer = 0 To count
        Dim ping As Ping = New Ping()
        Dim pingReply As PingReply = ping.Send(address)
        Dim contents As String =
            String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}",
                          DateTime.Now, vbTab, address,
                          vbTab, pingReply.Status, vbCrLf)
        File.AppendAllText(log, contents)
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:

```
10/2/2014 9:24:20 PM    www.yahoo.com   Success
10/2/2014 9:24:21 PM    www.yahoo.com   Success
10/2/2014 9:24:22 PM    www.yahoo.com   Success
10/2/2014 9:24:23 PM    www.yahoo.com   Success
10/2/2014 9:24:24 PM    www.yahoo.com   Success
10/2/2014 9:24:25 PM    www.yahoo.com   Success
```

Comment: So with that it shows whether or not it was a success, but is there a way to log all of the ping statistics with it?

Comment: Yes, there is an example that shows how to retrieve more details about the ping : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144955(v=vs.110).aspx. You can (should) append them to the string as I've shown, using `vbTab` you will have an easier time when parsing the log or opening it in Excel for instance.